# How to get username in IIS windows authentication on frontend side?

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-authentication

In IIS I have created 2 separate sites for UI & API. On UI side I am using Angular 7 & in Backend its .net core 2.2 webapi.
I have enabled the windows authentication in UI site IIS but I am not able to fetch value of username on frontend side. Is there is any way that I can fetch the username on frontend side from windows prompt?

For workaround I have also created a backend api which is giving me current user name but its giving me only when I am enabling the windows authentication in API site of IIS.If I disable the windows auth. in API site then this API gives me 500 Internal Server error.

But I just wanted to enable the windows authentication on UI site only.
1. Please let me know if there is any way that I can transfer this username from UI site to API??
 or 
2.If I can fetch this username on fronend part only through any angular buit in service or package.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, angular runs context of the current HTML document, so it won't be able to determine anything about a current user. Since the server will not return anything which related with the current login in user in the response.

It would be a huge security risk if a browser access to that kind of personal information